# Correctly override proguard options

Tags: android, proguard

I'm playing with ProGuard in my current project and decided to try optimized android config (with gradle):

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

I didn't find any clear documentation about optimizations performed by proguard and android versions which are compatible with them:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
```

Are they up-to-date if app min sdk version is 11?

So i decided to override it to give it a try in `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-optimizations **
-printconfiguration "result.pro"
```

But final configuration isn't as i expected. It contains all rules combined:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*,**
```

So how can option be correctly overridden in ProGuard? Or may be this line equals to `-optimizations **` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a bit of trial and error but eventually found out. To override the default ProGuard optimizations to, for example, apply everything but `code/simplification/arithmetic` then:

1. Add a `-optimizations` line to your ProGuard file and use `*` to represent *all*. For example, the following line:

   ```
   -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,*
   ```

   means "enable all optimizations except `code/simplification/arithmetic`". The list of available optimizations is available in [the official website](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/optimizations) and you can use `*` to enable/disable classes of optimizations (e.g. `!field/*`).
2. You have to make sure that your ProGuard rules file is loaded before the default ProGuard file by swapping the order of `proguard-rules.pro` and `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` in the Gradle file so that `proguard-rules.pro` appears first:

   ```
   buildTypes {
     release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro', getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
     }
   }
   ```

The output should look something like this now:

```
Optimizing...
  Number of finalized classes:                 68
  Number of unboxed enum classes:              1
  Number of vertically merged classes:         0
  Number of horizontally merged classes:       3
  Number of removed write-only fields:         0   (disabled)
  Number of privatized fields:                 58
  Number of inlined constant fields:           375
  Number of privatized methods:                13
  Number of staticized methods:                37
  Number of finalized methods:                 210
  Number of removed method parameters:         290
  Number of inlined constant parameters:       236
  Number of inlined constant return values:    239
  Number of inlined short method calls:        35
  Number of inlined unique method calls:       114
  Number of inlined tail recursion calls:      0
  Number of merged code blocks:                4
  Number of variable peephole optimizations:   723
  Number of arithmetic peephole optimizations: 10
  Number of cast peephole optimizations:       0
  Number of field peephole optimizations:      0
  Number of branch peephole optimizations:     42
  Number of string peephole optimizations:     35
  Number of simplified instructions:           369
  Number of removed instructions:              5019
  Number of removed local variables:           154
  Number of removed exception blocks:          0
  Number of optimized local variable frames:   201
```